# I am not able to sync my android project as it was build on another PC. How to solve it?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

[image: error log is in the image]

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript [poiu{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[poiu` from the `buildscript [poiu{`, that should be `buildscript {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buildscript **[poiu**{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the code wrapped in * - the code there should be purely buildscript without the [poui at all.

As to how this happened; It might be copy-paste error(paste in wrong place) or it might be accidental code writing. The point is to fix it. Gradle build errors are not as detailed and the IDE does not show error in the same way the java(or C++ etc) compilers and IDE's show them.